# change Firefox font size based on window location in multi-monitor setup

Tags: firefox, multiple-monitors, autohotkey, dpi, high-dpi

My laptop monitor has a much higher pixel density then my external monitors, and I'd like to be able to increase Firefox's global font size using something like [NoSquint](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nosquint/), but only when the window is placed on the laptop's monitor.

I'm thinking of an [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/)-based solution. Are there any other options over there, or perhaps someone already has an Autohotkey script that solves this?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this in AHK just now as a solution (since you mentioned the wonderful tool). To use it, set `Z1`, `Z2`, etc. to the desired zoom levels shown in the legend. (If nothing is set for a display it will maximize at 100% zoom.) Then, you can combine <kbd>Alt</kbd> with the number key corresponding to any display's number to maximize/zoom Firefox on that display. For example:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to maximize the active FF window to zoom level `Z1` on the primary display
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to maximize the active FF window to zoom level `Z2` on the secondary display

Code:

```
; Set the zoom levels for FF to maximize to on each display
Z1 = 4  ; Primary display zoom level
Z2 = 0  ; Secondary display zoom level
Z3 = 0  ; etc..

; Zoom level legend
;   0 = 100%        3 = 133%        6 = 200%
;   1 = 110%        4 = 150%        7 = 240%
;   2 = 120%        5 = 170%        8 = 300%

; Count displays and create hotkeys accordingly
sysGet, monitors, 80
loop %monitors% {
    sysGet, screen, monitor, %a_index%
    %a_index%_screenTop := screenTop
    %a_index%_screenLeft := screenLeft
    hotkey, ifWinActive, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
    hotkey, $!%a_index%, moveMaxZoom
}

moveMaxZoom:
    winRestore  ; Restore window if necessary
    thisHotkey := regExReplace(a_thisHotkey, "[^0-9A-Za-z]")
    winMove, a,, %thisHotkey%_screenLeft, %thisHotkey%_screenTop
    postMessage, 0x112, 0xF030  ; 0x112 = WM_SYSCOMMAND, 0xF030 = SC_MAXIMIZE
    Z := Z%thisHotkey%
    send ^0^{+ %Z%}
return
```